# Has there been a NBA Father-Son Duos that have won an NBA Title and Olympic Gold Medal?

Tags: basketball, olympics, nba

I am curious, with 2nd generation players that have come through the NBA, Has there been a NBA player who is a father to another NBA player and both have won a NBA Title and a gold medal in the Olympics?

Comment: [List of second-generation National Basketball Association players](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_second-generation_National_Basketball_Association_players) on Wikipedia might help when searching. (Of course, I cannot vouch for the completeness. The references provided in that Wikipedia article might be useful too.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Disclaimer: Wikipedia lists cannot be considered the ultimate reference, although my limited research has shown no discrepancy in case of this record.*

[This Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_second-generation_National_Basketball_Association_players) covers the second generation basketball players in the NBA, and mentions four father-son duos to have won the NBA Championship (in that order).

- Matt Guokas Sr. and Matt Guokas Jr.
- Rick Barry and Brent Barry
- Bill Walton and Luke Walton
- Mychal Thompson and Klay Thompson

Comparing that with [the list of Olympic medalists in basketball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_medalists_in_basketball) shows only one of those eight players has won an Olympic medal (any Olympic medal), i.e Klay Thompson who won Olympic gold in Rio in 2016. So to answer your question, there are no father-son duos who are both NBA champions and Olympic gold medalists. Interestingly, had you posed this question four months earlier, there would have been no one from a father-son NBA champion duo to have claimed an Olympic medal.

Comment: That's interesting to know that not one of those players actually won a gold medal, let alone, any medal in the Olympics other than Klay Thompson.

Answer (score 0):

With the Golden State Warriors' latest championship triumph, add the father-son combo of [Bob McAdoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_McAdoo) (L.A. Lakers) and [James Michael McAdoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Michael_McAdoo).

Comment: I have originally added the Wikipedia links mainly for benefit of other users who want to know more about the two players. But when I read them I also noticed this claim: "(Bob) McAdoo's second cousin, Ronnie McAdoo, is the father of James Michael McAdoo, who also played for the Tar Heels and became an NBA player." So if the information in the WP articles is correct, they are not father and son.